# using path in a function in R

Tags: r, function, path, directory

Have this. Seems simple but throws an error when asking for a result.

```
directory <- setwd("C:/Users/Spin/Documents/R/pollutant/specdata")
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332){
file.list <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)
cum_vector = numeric()

 for(i in id){
   data <- read.csv(file.list(i))
   cum_vector < - c(cum_vector, data[[pollutant]])
 }

 mean(cum_vector, na.rm = TRUE)
}

pollutantmean(1:10)
```

> Error in list.files(path = directory, pattern = ".csv", full.names =
>   TRUE) :    invalid 'path' argument

used `file.path` as well

Answer (score 1):

Note that this question is a homework assignment for the Johns Hopkins *R Programming* course on Coursera. I'll explain why the code fails but won't just give you a complete answer because that would violate the Coursera Honor Code.

This code fails because `pollutantmean(1:10)` passes a numeric vector as the argument `directory`. Since there is no directory `1:10`, the code fails with an invalid path error.

The `pollutantmean()` function has three arguments and should be called like this in order to calculate the mean of the `sulfate` pollutant on the first 10 pollution sensors:

```
pollutantmean("specdata","sulfate",1:10)
```

Also, instead of hard coding the directory, the function is supposed to parse the directory passed in the first argument into the required path to access the pollution files that should be stored in a `specdata` subdirectory from the current R working directory.

There is also an error in the assignment statement for the `cum_vector` vector, and I'll leave that to you to correct on your own.

Comment: Len,Thank you for any help. After watching hours of various videos, doing all the coursera assignments, i am stuck on something that seems simple and I think I am missing the tree in front of me for the forest. I appreciate your approach. Thank you.

Comment: @RJP - take a look at [Resources for R Programming](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-rprogrammingResources.md) and especially [Forms of the Extract Operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md), both of which are highly relevant to the programming assignments.